# Default generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

So i have a protractor list page object. That object defaults to returning `ElementFinder` instances, but it can be customized to return `ComplexType` instances like so:

```
class ComplexType {
  foo = 'foo';

  constructor(public element: ElementFinder) {}
}

const list = new List<ComplexType>({ element: ..., type: ComplexType});
expect(list.get(0).foo).toBe('foo');
```

Here is the page object definition:

```
import { ElementFinder } from 'protractor';

export interface ListItem<T> {
  new(element: ElementFinder): T;
}

export interface ListOptions<T> {
  element: ElementFinder;
  selector?: string;
  type?: ListItem<T>;
}

export class List<T = ElementFinder> {
  public readonly element: ElementFinder;
  private selector: string;
  private type: (element: ElementFinder) => T;

  get items() {
    return this.element.$$(this.selector);
  }

  get length() {
    return this.items.count();
  }

  constructor(options: ListOptions<T> | ElementFinder, selector?: string) {
    if (options instanceof ElementFinder) {
      this.element = options;
      this.selector = selector || 'li';
      this.type = (element: ElementFinder) => element;
    } else {
      this.element = options.element;
      this.selector = options.selector || 'li';
      this.type = (element: ElementFinder) => new options.type(element);
    }
  }

  get(index: number): T {
    return this.type(this.items.get(index));
  }
}
```

The problem i'm having is that typescript doesn't understand that T sometimes is ElementFinder. So when i return an instance of ElementFinder it complains that element finder does not match T.

I'm stumped. Surely this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that within the class, `T` is not known to be anything specific (even if you do some checking, the compiler will not narrow `T` in any way). What this means is that all assignments must work for any conceivable `T`, and since `this.type = (element: ElementFinder) => element;` will not work for any `T` it will give an error.

The quick and dirty fix is to use a type assertion, if we are sure this is a false positive:

```
this.type = (element: ElementFinder) => element as any;
```

The more elegant solution would be to change `type` to required, and pass in the appropriate function:

```
class ComplexType {
    foo = 'foo';

    constructor(public element: ElementFinder) { }
}

export interface ListOptions<T> {
    element: ElementFinder;
    selector?: string;
    type: (element: ElementFinder) => T;
}

export class List<T = ElementFinder> {
    public readonly element: ElementFinder;
    private selector: string;
    private type: (element: ElementFinder) => T;

    get items() {
        return this.element.$$(this.selector);
    }

    get length() {
        return this.items.count();
    }
    public static default(element: ElementFinder, selector = 'li') :ListOptions<ElementFinder>{
        return {
            element,
            selector,
            type : (e) => e
        }
    }
    constructor(options: ListOptions<T>, selector?: string) {
        this.element = options.element;
        this.selector = options.selector || 'li';
        this.type = options.type;
    }

    get(index: number): T {
        return this.type(this.items.get(index));
    }
}
let element!: ElementFinder;

// complex usage
const list1 = new List<ComplexType>({ element, type: e=> new ComplexType(e) });
//default usage
const list2 = new List(List.default(element));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!